# Remove block from Product Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, page, remove

I want to remove right side block from product page.
See https://prnt.sc/r5mlfi
How can i remove this? What is the name of this block?

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-">
            <container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" />
            <container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" />
            <container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" />

            <!-- Static blocks -->
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper -->
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" />

    <!-- Move some blocks to new positions -->
    <!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> -->
    <!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> -->
    <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
    <move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
    <!-- <move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> -->

    <!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file -->
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper" />

    <!-- Product collateral data (tabs) -->
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" template="Infortis_Base::product/view/details.phtml" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="show_tabs" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::showTabs" />
        </arguments>
        <!-- Custom static blocks as tabs -->
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block1" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab1</argument>
                <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle">
                    <param name="id">block_product_tab1</param>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab2</argument>
                <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle">
                    <param name="id">block_product_tab2</param>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" />
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getUpsellProductsTemplate" />
            <!-- TODO: -->
            <!-- <argument name="is_responsive" xsi:type="string">false</argument>
            <argument name="show_items" xsi:type="string">3</argument> -->
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Infortis_Base::product/list/slider.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>



</body>
```

Comment: please add image irectly here the link your provided is broken

Comment: add your app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_ptoduct_view.xml file code here.

Comment: It will be your theme settings. you can find this from your admin panel theme settings > product page settings. you can remove from there

Comment: @KishorThummar i have added in my question. Check

Comment: @Nafisa are you using any purchased theme ?

Comment: @Nafisa check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below line in the same file in the `<body>` tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="block_product_secondary_bottom" remove="true"/>
```

or you can find the "`block_product_secondary_bottom`" block in `Admin->Content->Blocks` and **Disable** it.

Flush the cache and check.

Comment: Thanx, It worked.Now how can the product page be fit to full width. I dont want this blank space . See https://prnt.sc/r5navo

Comment: Not sure but you can try to remove these blocks like above in your XML and check. container_product_secondary_1 and container_product_secondary_2

Comment: Check this guide: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/elabos-files/PDF/Ultimo%202%20User%20Guide.pdf and find the go to page no.171 and check the Example 3 for this

Comment: Thanx. The biggest problem is what ever configuration i am doing here is not getting reflected in my frontend. Even the css. Why so, i  had to write custom css to change the button colors and all. Which is wrong. How can i resolve this first. I had made a child theme for my main infortis theme. is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Stores > Configurations > Advanced > Developer > Debug > **Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront** to **Yes**

and Also

> Enable **Hints for Storefront with URL Parameter** to **Yes**
>
> Enable **Add Block Class Type** to Hints to **Yes**

[image]

Now go to your frontend store page and at the end of the URL of page add '**?templatehints=magento**' and hit enter.

and you'll get the name of the Block.

and to Remove the block use below line in layout file,

```
<referenceBlock name="your.block.name.you.want.to.remove" remove="true"/>
```